# Efficient way to do a join between dataframe when joining field is unique

Tags: apache-spark, join, key-value

I have 2 dataframes in Spark. Both of them have an id which is unique.
The structure is the following

```
df1:
id_df1   values
abc     abc_map_value
cde     cde_map_value
fgh     fgh_map_value


df2:
id_df2   array_id_df1
123      [abc, fgh]
456      [cde]
```

I want to get the following dataframe result:

```
result_df:
id_df2     array_values
123       [map(abc,abc_map_value), map(fgh,fgh_map_value)]
456       [map(cde,cde_map_value)]
```

I can use spark sql to do so but i don't think that it's the most efficient way as ids are unique.

Is there a way to store a key/values dictionary in memory to lookup for the value based on the key rather than to do a join ? Would it be more efficient than to do a join ?

Comment: you can use [broadcast variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673773/how-to-use-a-broadcast-collection-in-a-udf/40676271#40676271) as lookup tables if one your datasets isn't too big.

Answer (score 0):

If you explode the df2 into key,value pairs, the join becomes easy and just a groupBy is needed.

You could experiment other aggregations & reductions for more efficiency / parallelisation

```
df2
  .select('id_df2, explode('array_id_df1).alias("id_df1"))
  .join(df1, usingColumn="id_df1")
  .groupBy('id_df2)
  .agg(collect_list(struct('id_df1, 'values)).alias("array_values"))
```